# Python: Selenium chromedriver not work for button click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wish to used the selenium python to click the button but error, below is my python code for clicking the button:

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id^='rallybutton-1121-btnIconEl']").click()
```

OR

```
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rallybutton-1121-btnIconEI"]').click()
```

OR

```
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rallybutton-1121"]').click()
```

AND etc also not workable

And below is my inspect element:

```
<a class="x4-btn secondary rly-small x4-unselectable x4-btn-default-small x4-icon x4-btn-icon x4-btn-default-small-icon" style="float:right;border-width:0;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" tabindex="0" id="rallybutton-1121" role="button">
   <span id="rallybutton-1121-btnWrap" role="presentation" class="x4-btn-wrap" unselectable="on"><span id="rallybutton-1121-btnEl" class="x4-btn-button" role="presentation">

     <span id="rallybutton-1121-btnInnerEl" class="x4-btn-inner x4-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span>

        <span role="presentation" id="rallybutton-1121-btnIconEl" class="x4-btn-icon-el icon-export " unselectable="on" style="">&nbsp;</span>
     </span>
   </span>
</a>
```

[image]

My button look like this:

[image]

And I wish to click the Export to CSV...

[image]

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SMANE\Desktop\ShiJieTest\ShIJieRally.py", line 54, in <module>
#br.find_element_by_id('rallybutton-1121').click()#rallybutton-1084-btnIconEl
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: Your stack-trace (line 393) suggests that you're actually using X path to locate the button web-element rather than the ID. can you show your code around your line 41? What confuses me is it looks like the selenium library itself is calling the locator for Xpath  "(return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = xpath))" rather than using the Id. Xpath is known to vary quite a lot even with the same element so it's better to use the id because its more stable. If that doesn't work your id might be changing for some reason so try using a different locator like Class.

Comment: I would just like to add two things: the code that actually is clicking your button in your code is shown in the stack-trace and it doesn't seem to correspond with the code you posted on top. The line 41 in your code seems to be the problem and my guess is that 'nameField.click()' defaults to locating by X path which is then causing your 'NoSuchElement' Exception because x path is an unreliable locator that changes often. Another thing I notice is that your button seems to be 'unselectable' in your inspect element window. That might be causing the exception as well.

Comment: @ShiJieTio Update the question with text based HTML

Comment: @Redacted I have updated my error

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're using an ID locator correctly in which case @cruisepandey has the best answer for you: the button id is dynamic so it changes and isnt constantly 'rallybutton-1121' thus the NoSuchElement Exception. I would recomend using Class as the selector, it tends to be more stable. Another thing thats relatively stable is the actual text of the button. I don't believe its a built in command (pretty sure links have a by-text function automatically) but I'm sure you could easily make something to find/match button text unless there are multiple buttons with the same text.

Comment: The button actually without  text, this is a button when click it will drop down another 3 buttons, but for the main button also not able to click, I have change to class also face the same error, @Redacted any ideas? Please help I really stuck on this few months already, thanks

Comment: While its not the best, It might be your only option. if the button is dynamic then the only constant might be its xpath location/index. You would want to start from a stable webelement and work your way down with an xpath expression to the button. If you have access to the developers for this website, tell them to make real ids, otherwise xpath expressions that burrow down to the button are your best bet. Here is an article that explains this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-handling-dynamic-web-elements-selenium-raju-tandukar

Comment: @Newcontributor I have updated the question in html based, thanks

Comment: @ShiJieTio You seem to have added a lot of additional information in the form of comments. Can you update the main question with those information for a better analysis?

Comment: @Newcontributor I have update my question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **ID** `rallybutton-1121` you are using in your code looks quite dynamic.

You can extract **rallybutton** from ID  using a css selector like this :

```
a[id^='rallybutton']
```

code would be :

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id^='rallybutton']").click()
```

**Recommendation** : Check `a[id^='rallybutton']` in dev tool, just to make sure there should be only one entry .

Consider adding **WebDriverWait** in your code for more stability.

Hope this helps.